# How to create bool filter query with nested bool should query using NEST OIS

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm having trouble with using NEST to create this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"status": 0}},
        {"term": {"freeRound": false }},
        {"term": {"playerId": 189149 }},
        {
          "range": {
            "eventTime": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2019-05-02T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2019-05-02T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {"term": {"extGameId": 527 }},
              {"term": {"extGameId": 804 }},
              {"term": {"extGameId": 9503 }}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {"term": {"transactionType": 3 }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byGames": {
      "terms": {"field": "extGameId" }
    },
    "sumAgg": {
        "sum": {"field": "amount"}
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen, my query is using bool filter as I don't need scoring. Inside I have those `TermQuery` with `DateRange` part which should be met (status, freeRound, playerId and Date range), and then a sub bool should part, saying that one of extGamesId must be met.

Now here is my code using NEST trying to achieve same:

```
//playerId, gameList, startDate and endDate are passed as a parameters

var filters = new List<QueryContainer>();

filters.Add(new TermQuery { Field = new Field("status"), Value = "0" });//status=0
filters.Add(new TermQuery {Field = new Field("freeRound"), Value = false});//freeRound = false
filters.Add(new TermQuery { Field = new Field("playerId"), Value = playerId });//playerId
filters.Add(endDate != null ? 
    new DateRangeQuery
    {
        Field = new Field("eventTime"),
        GreaterThanOrEqualTo = startDate,
        LessThanOrEqualTo = endDate
    } : 
    new DateRangeQuery
    {
        Field = new Field("eventTime"),
        GreaterThanOrEqualTo = startDate
    });

if (gameList.Count > 0)
{
    var shouldFilter = new List<QueryContainer>();
    gameList.ForEach(g => shouldFilter.Add(new TermQuery { Field = new Field("extGameId"), Value = g }));//extGameIds

    filters.Add(new BoolQuery { Should = shouldFilter, MinimumShouldMatch = 1 });
}

filters.Add(new TermQuery { Field = new Field("transactionType"), Value = 3 });//transactionType

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<SomethingHere>()
{
    Query = new BoolQuery
    {
        Filter = filters
    },
    Aggregations = new SumAggregation("sum_agg", "amount")

};

var responsesResult = _client.Search<SomethingHere>(searchRequest);
```

However, I'm getting "Input string was not in a correct format." error.
Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here are the relevant mappings:

```
  "amount": {
    "type": "double"
  },
  "eventTime": {
    "type": "date"
  },
  "extGameId": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "freeRound": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "playerId": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "status": {
    "type": "keyword"
  }
  "transactionType": {
    "type": "short"
  }
```

And here is POCO:

```
[Number(NumberType.Double)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
[Date]
public DateTime eventTime { get; set; }
[Keyword]
public string ExtGameId { get; set; }
[Boolean]
public decimal FreeRound { get; set; }
[Number(NumberType.Long)]
public long PlayerId { get; set; }
[Keyword]
public string Status { get; set; }
[Number(NumberType.Short)]
public int TransactionType { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you have your class, (SomethingHere) why not use nest in order to avoir type error (QueryContainer filterContainer = null, filterContainer &= Query<SomethingHere>.QueryString(q
                    => q.Query("0").Fields(f => f.Field(fi => fi.status))); for exemple ?

If you want keep your code like that just comment some lines, you will find the one with the error. We cant reproduice it because we dont have SomethingHere class and your es mapping.

Comment: Hi @LeBigCat, thanks for your answer, I've edited my post with mappings and POCO.

Comment: I'm getting the same error if I split Q and extract the should part:`var filtersShould = new List<QueryContainer>();
                gameList.ForEach(g => filtersShould.Add(new TermQuery { Field = new Field("extGameId"), Value = g }));` and then add it to search request as a `Should` part: `var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<SomethingHere>()
                {
                    Query = new BoolQuery
                    {
                        Must = filtersMust,
                        Should = filtersShould
                    },
                    ...

                };`

Comment: This work on my side. I thinck the problem is not with your querry but with mappings (date? or maybe nullable field in a document) could give error, how do you insert / update document? You only use nest with this Poco to create them or you got different application who can modify your document? Can you make some test with your querry with different input value (=> to return only one document for exemple)

Comment: Hi, thanks once again. I've come to the same conclusion the other day ago when I set `"size":0` param to my query and everything went well. But what is strange is the error messages I'm getting in response (before size: 0) like '..expecting 'false | true' bat saw '"false"'...' and other times I get: '..expecting Number.Token but saw '"3"'...' FYI I'm not indexing the data through my app, data is sent via FiileBeat->Logstash to Elasticsearch

Comment: @cagi what version of Elasticsearch are you using, and what version of Nest? The error sounds like a deserialization error where the field is a numeric string value, but is mapped as a numeric value on your POCO. If you can provide version numbers for each you're using, I'll be able to provide more details

Comment: As he imports document using a different tool (logstash), first i all, i would look at for nullable value for each no string field....

Comment: I'm using the latest available version of NEST(7.0.0-alpha2) and trying to query Elasticsearch (7.0)